# I need to be able to insert values from textboxes into an access database ,but as of now its not working

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am not being able to insert values from textboxes into the access database, Here's the code ,It shows the error "no value given for required parameters"

```
 firstname = fname.Text
        middlename = mname.Text
        lastname = lname.Text
        address = addr.Text
        accountplan = accplan.SelectedItem
        accounttype = acctype.SelectedItem
        accountname = firstname + " " + middlename + " " + lastname
        Dim accessconn As New  _
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & "avalanche.mdb")
        Dim com As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Try
            accessconn.Open()
            MsgBox("Access succesfully connected")
            com = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO account(firstname,middlename,lastname) VALUES(firstname,middlename,lastname)", accessconn)
            com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            accessconn.Close()
            Return
        Catch ex As Exception
            accessconn.Close()
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            Return
        End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set values :

```
    firstname = fname.Text
    middlename = mname.Text
    lastname = lname.Text
    address = addr.Text
    accountplan = accplan.SelectedItem
    accounttype = acctype.SelectedItem
    accountname = firstname + " " + middlename + " " + lastname
    Dim accessconn As New  _
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & "avalanche.mdb")
    Dim com As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Try
        accessconn.Open()
        MsgBox("Access succesfully connected")
        com = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO account(firstname,middlename,lastname) VALUES('"& firstname &"','"& middlename &"','"& lastname &"')", accessconn)
        com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        accessconn.Close()
        Return
    Catch ex As Exception
        accessconn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Return
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi adding Record to access table is simple just go like that

```
firstname = fname.Text
middlename = mname.Text
lastname = lname.Text
address = addr.Text
accountplan = accplan.SelectedItem
accounttype = acctype.SelectedItem
accountname = firstname + " " + middlename + " " + lastname

dim conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & "avalanche.mdb"

dim con as new oledbConnection

con.connectionstring = conString
con.open()

cmd.connection = con
cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO account(firstname,middlename,lastname) VALUES('"& firstname & "','" & middlename & "','" & lastname & "')"
cmd.executeNonQuery


msgbox "Record Saved"

con.close()
```

Do post back if you are getting any error I will be glad to Help.

Regards.